# Require.js optimizer is only minifying main.js and ignoring 'paths'

Tags: requirejs

main.js:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/',

  paths: {
    'd3': 'lib/d3',
    'text': 'lib/text',
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
    'topojson': 'lib/topojson',
    'statecodes': 'lib/statecodes',
    'underscore': 'lib/underscore'
  },

  shim: {
    'lib/bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'lib/backbone': {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'lib/wreqr': {
      deps: ['lib/backbone']
    },
    'lib/marionette': {
      deps: ['lib/wreqr'],
      exports: 'Marionette'
    }
  }
});

var deps = [
  'app',
  'utils/dataserver',
  'd3',
  'text',
  'jquery',
  'topojson',
  'statecodes',
  'underscore',
  'lib/bootstrap',
  'lib/backbone',
  'lib/marionette'
];

require(deps, function(app, ds) {
  app.start();
  ds.fetchall();
});
```

The config file app.build.js:

```
({
  baseUrl: "../js",
  name: 'main',
  mainConfigFile: '../js/main.js',
  out: "../js/build.js"
})
```

By running `r.js -o app.build.js` I was expecting the optimizer to minify and concatenate the scripts inside `path`. But all it does is minify `main.js`. What am I missing?

Output of `r.js -o app.build.js`:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Uglifying file: /Project/web/js/build.js

/Project/web/js/build.js
----------------
/Project/web/js/main.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the literal array of dependencies, not the variable `deps,` as the first argument to `require.` Otherwise, the optimizer doesn't know what files to include.

Answer (score 0):

`r.js` will only trace through all the dependencies that it finds are needed for your application. You need to include the entry point `require([], function() {});` inside `main.js`, or basically the beginning `require` block that should be included in the script specified in `data-main` when using RequireJS regularly.

Comment: I made an edit to the post and added the `require()` call. However, that did not change the behavior of running `r.js`.

Comment: Can you try removing the `mainConfigFile` property from your build file?

Comment: Hmm that should work. Try skipping the build file altogether and just do `node r.js -o name=main out=build.js` inside the js directory.